# Spring listener IntrospectorCleanupListener

Tags: spring, listener

the document about `IntrospectorCleanupListener` in spring framework mentioned that this listener should be registered as the first one in web.xml.

> ...
>   *
>
> **This listener should be registered as the first one in {@code web.xml},
>   * before any application listeners such as Spring's ContextLoaderListener.**
>   * This allows the listener to take full effect at the right time of the lifecycle.
>   *
>   * @author Juergen Hoeller
>   * @since 1.1
>   * @see java.beans.Introspector#flushCaches()
>   * @see org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults#acceptClassLoader
>   * @see org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults#clearClassLoader
>   */

why it should be put as the first one? what will happen if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listeners are executed in the order they are found. So the first one is executed at first at startup and as last on shutdown. See [ServletContextListener execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729370/servletcontextlistener-execution-order) for more information on that.

If this particular `ServletContextListener` wouldn't be the first, it wouldn't be able to flush all the cached results as it would miss the already loaded ones or it would flush all of them to early which could cause issues with other classes.

Comment: got it. thanks for your quick response. I am really appreciated.